# Restore netplan

Tags: netplan

I have removed netplan from Ubuntu 22.04 and now the network is not working, I cannot install the netplan again as internet is not working. How can I restore the network?

Comment: You didn't clarify what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're using, Servers use netplan, Desktops use NetworkManager.  As you specifically mention *netplan*, you're talking about a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server system (*no desktop added*).

Comment: I am not sure about it but I accidentally ran this command sudo apt remove netplan* and after that the network option was removed and net is also not working on the system. I check in about and it is showing Ubuntu 22.04.2  LTS

Comment: I'm on a desktop system, my machine has netplan installed too - however if your system is a desktop system & netplan is fully restored; you won't have full network capabilities of a desktop due to missing *Network Manager*.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses Netplan, however other Ubuntu 22.04 LTS systems including Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and *flavors* (which are also desktop systems) use more than just *netplan.io*

Answer (score 1):

You could download each package and dependency for your architecture manually on another machine, put them on a USB stick and copy them into a directory: `/path/to/netplan/packages`. Then install all packages in that directory with:

```
sudo dpkg -Ri /path/to/netplan/packages
```

You can retrieve the latest packages and dependencies from the [official Ubuntu package archive](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/netplan.io).

Comment: I did it but the network option is not showing on the system, what to do ?

Comment: Hmm maybe you also removed Network-Manager. Perhaps a complete reinstall is the best option.

Comment: You mean ubuntu installation or network manager ? I net is now working then how should I install the network manager ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall network-manager`. But since you weren't too specific about what you removed, it's hard to guess.

Comment: I ran this command `sudo apt remove netplan*`

Comment: If you have a related question, please ask a new question. Your exact question (Netplan removed, and net not working) has been answered.